# O365 archiving per project

Tags: microsoft-outlook, archiving, office365

is there any way to use one of the archiving features in office (personal archive, legal hold, ...) to achieve project archiving.
The idea is that users can choose themselves to archive a mail. This archive must be available to several users to use and to read from.

At the moment we have some projects on the fileshare, that allows for everyone writing together but isn't really a practical solution (for viewing and searching).
Some smaller projects that have little people cooperating use a pst; if they need it the add it to outlook and afterwards the disconnect it again.

any ideas how I could get that?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a non-user resource called ProjectArchive that everyone has access to by adding as a separate mailbox. You can create folders and assign that folder specific read/write permission. Everyone else would only get read access. This way, only certain people to add/remove project e-mails, but everyone could search the archive. The search would be handled by the Office 365 servers that Microsoft runs.

The other option is to add a [Site Mailbox but you need SharePoint.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-project-emails-and-documents-from-one-place-a9925c7c-7731-4ae4-b8fe-73c153bfb73f)

Comment: great answer, I didn't know about both possibilities. I leave the question open to see if there are other possibilities, but I will investigate these ones.